# how to set a PrimeFaces theme?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get my PrimeFaces (v2.1) app to use a different theme.

I downloaded vader-1.0.0.jar and put it in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

I added the following to my web.xml:

```
<context-param>   
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>vader</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

But when I run the app, the theme does not change.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

Using PrimeFaces 2.1 I just put

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/cupertino/skin.css"/>
```

inside `<h:head>` of the page (in my case, a template). Nothing else.. And it worked!

Answer (score 7):

You can define the theme dynamically like that:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{themeBeam.applicationTheme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

the Bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ThemeBean {

    public String getApplicationTheme() {
        return "dark-hive";
    }

}
```

Comment: @Robert Hume, hello, it´s been a while but, do you know a way of loading all primefaces themes in a drop down in the view. Right now I can switch themes dynamically, but I am populating the list manually, is there a way to populate the list of themes programmatically? thanks

Answer (score 3):

<s>At least in PrimeFaces 2.2, the correct parameter in `web.xml` is `primefaces.SKIN`:</s>

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

***Edit*** from [@Cagatay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306753/cagatay-civici) comment: *"primefaces.THEME is the official parameter name, others are deprecated and will be removed in 3.0."*

This allows me to dynamically specify a skin using a session-scoped bean:

```
@Named @SessionScoped
public class LayoutBean
{
    ...
    private String theme = "aristo";
    ...
    public String getTheme()
    {
        return theme;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/#{layoutBean.theme}/skin.css" />
```

Comment: According to this page it's "primefaces.THEME", but I'll try SKIN and see if it works.  http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html

Comment: "SKIN" didn't make any difference. :(

Comment: @Robert: I believe that `primefaces.THEME` may be a deprecated (but still functional) parameter name. The other problem may be the location of the jar - but I haven't tried doing it this way. In the past, I have just extracted the CSS and image files (as my answer hints).

Comment: @Robert I noticed you posted over on the [PrimeFaces support forum](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7708&sid=9dbb53aac01f9795bbf427a7e0d15d27) as well, good to see the actual markup that gets generated. Upgrading to PF 2.2 isn't an option for you, is it?

Comment: Hi Matt, I had problems deploying PF 2.2 when I started this app, but I just tried PF 2.2 again and it seems fine.  Also, in PF 2.2 the theme appears with the "primefaces.THEME" specified, no manual extraction or tweaking required.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: primefaces.THEME is the official parameter name, others are deprecated and will be removed in 3.0.

Comment: @Cagatay Civici: wont using this `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/cupertino/skin.css"/>` alone work ?

Answer (score 3):

Theme packaged in a jar is supported since Primefaces 2.2 **final**.

"primefaces.THEME" replaces "primefaces.SKIN" in web.xml.