# How to set theme by Java code in Primefaces 3?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have for example theme `test`. How to set this theme using Java code in Primefaces ? I don't want to use context param `primefaces.THEME` and i don't want to use `<p:themeSwitcher>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save theme in Primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148680/how-to-save-theme-in-primefaces)

Answer (score 6):

One more way to do this: include stylesheet to your pages template:

`<h:body> 
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-#{themesBean.theme}" name="theme.css" /> 
</h:body>`

Where #{themesBean.theme} variable reffers to name of your theme.

P.S. tested in PF5

Same answer on similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092773/2993327

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do (untested, but should give you an indication how it should work)

- Disable standard theme support (in web.xml):

Code:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

- Make a managed bean (CDI or std JSF) that holds the value for the theme.

Code:

```
@Named @SessionScoped
public class LayoutBean
{
    ...
    private String theme = "test";
    ...
    public String getTheme()
    {
        return theme;
    }
    ...
}
```

- Add following tag in the head of all your pages (template)

Code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/themes/{layoutBean.theme}/skin.css" />
```

You can find this solution on the following URL [how to set a PrimeFaces theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935496/how-to-set-a-primefaces-theme)