# How to save theme in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use Primefaces [ThemeSwitcher](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/themeswitcher.jsf). I'm interested how I can save the selected theme when I reload the web application. For example how I can set the theme name as variable from database?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be needing the ThemeSwitcher to effect the kind of persistence you're looking for.

Simply perform the database lookup for the theme in a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and then store the value in the servlet context, possibly overriding whatever you've set in the web.xml

```
   public Class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){

      String selectedTheme = myThemeDAO.getConfiguredTheme();

      sce.getServletContext().setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME",selectedTheme);

     }


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

link your ThemeSwitcher component to a managedBean and add a listener linked to a ajax event:

```
<h:form id="form-theme">
<p:themeSwitcher id="defaultSwitcher" value="#{themeSwitcherBean.theme}">
<f:selectItems value="#{themeSwitcherBean.themes}" />
<p:ajax listener="#{themeSwitcherBean.saveTheme}" />
</p:themeSwitcher>
</h:form>
```

in your managedbean create the method who call saveTheme, that going to call a class to persist in database, and call the the class for the database when start to get the theme who had saved into the database:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="themeSwitcherBean")
public class ThemeSwitcherBean implements Serializable{ 
private Map<String, String> themes;
    private String theme;
    private GuestPreferences gp;

    private void setGp(GuestPreferences gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getThemes() {
        return themes;
    }

    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setGp(new GuestPreferences()); // persistent class
        setTheme(gp.getTheme()); // theme from the database;

        themes = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        themes.put("Aristo", "aristo");
        themes.put("Black-Tie", "black-tie");
        themes.put("Blitzer", "blitzer");
        themes.put("Bluesky", "bluesky");
        themes.put("Bootstrap", "bootstrap");
        themes.put("Casablanca", "casablanca");
        themes.put("Cupertino", "cupertino");
        themes.put("Dark-Hive", "dark-hive");
        themes.put("Dot-Luv", "dot-luv");
        themes.put("Eggplant", "eggplant");
        themes.put("Excite-Bike", "excite-bike");
        themes.put("Flick", "flick");
        themes.put("Glass-X", "glass-x");
        themes.put("Hot-Sneaks", "hot-sneaks");
        themes.put("Humanity", "humanity");
        themes.put("Le-Frog", "le-frog");
        themes.put("Midnight", "midnight");
        themes.put("Mint-Choc", "mint-choc");
        themes.put("Overcast", "overcast");
        themes.put("Pepper-Grinder", "pepper-grinder");
        themes.put("Redmond", "redmond");
        themes.put("Rocket", "rocket");
        themes.put("Sam", "sam");
        themes.put("Smoothness", "smoothness");
        themes.put("South-Street", "south-street");
        themes.put("Start", "start");
        themes.put("Sunny", "sunny");
        themes.put("Swanky-Purse", "swanky-purse");
        themes.put("Trontastic", "trontastic");
        themes.put("UI-Darkness", "ui-darkness");
        themes.put("UI-Lightness", "ui-lightness");
        themes.put("Vader", "vader");
    }

    public void saveTheme() {           
        gp.setTheme(theme); // theme to database
    }

}
```

method theme from class GuestPreferences is going to persist to the database

```
@SessionScoped
public class GuestPreferences {

    public String getTheme(){        
        //return the theme from the database
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme){
        //send the theme to the database
    }

}
```

the form to send and receive data from the database depends of you prefer: 
* jdbc 
* jta 
* jpa

for example, jta, make a persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="NAME-WHAT-YOU-WANT" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>CLASS-OF-YOUR-PROVIDER</provider>
    <jta-data-source>YOUR-DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
    <class>PATH-OF.GuestPreferences</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="NAME-OF-PROPERTY-TO-FORM-A-JDBC-URL" value="VALUE-OF-PROPERTY"/>
      <property name="NAME-OF-PROPERTY-TO-FORM-A-JDBC-URL" value="VALUE-OF-PROPERTY"/>
      <property name="NAME-OF-PROPERTY-TO-FORM-A-JDBC-URL" value="VALUE-OF-PROPERTY"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

in a resources class you can declare:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @Produces
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
```

then, you can use it in your GuestPreferences class:

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;

em.getTransaction().begin();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM user_table u where u.iduser=:iduser");
query.setParameter("iduser", "THEME-USER-ID");
User resultUser = (User) query.getResultList();
em.getTransaction().commit();
if(User!=null){ 
   return resultUser.getTheme();
 }
```

code above assumes you have a table called user_table where a user has a iduser, name ..., and a theme column, and it assumes you have an object called User to manage users

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do this: include stylesheet to your pages template:

`<h:body>
 <h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-#{themesBean.theme}" name="theme.css" /> </h:body>`

Where `#{themesBean.theme}` variable reffers to name of your theme.

P.S. tested in PF5

Answer (score 0):

I think setting selected theme in session would help:

```
session.setAttribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit web.xml through code:

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.at/2008/08/java-using-xmlbeans-to-edit-webxml.html

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>EDITME</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or create method before loading your page to choose the theme from db. (cleaner solution)